How to Migrate SOAP Project from Mule 3.9 to 4.5?
We're upgrading from Mule 3.9.0 to Mule 4.5.0 (Community Edition). We have a few Mule connectors that act as bridges between our application and some third party on the Internet using SOAP. Here is an example of the kind of thing we're trying to do:
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" basePath="/base" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="www.dneonline.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" />
<flow name="bridgeFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/app" allowedMethods="POST, GET" doc:name="Mule Listener" />
    <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://tempuri.org/" service="Calculator" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="bridge.wsdl" soapVersion="1.2" doc:name="CXF" />
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/calculator.asmx" method="POST" doc:name="Outside Requester" />
</flow>

In this example, the http:listener component receives a SOAP request to add 2 numbers. The http:request component forwards the SOAP envelope to an outside service that does simple math calculations on 2 numbers. The cxf:proxy-service allows Mule to expose it's endpoint as a SOAP based Webservice. The bridge.wsdl file it references is a copy of the wsdl from http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl, with stuff we don't care about removed.
In Mule 4, the cxf components are deprecated so there is no simple migration path. I have been experimenting with using an apikit-soap:router component to replace the cxf:proxy-service and a wsc:consume component to replace the http:request. Here's what I have so far:
<http:listener-config name="api-httpListenerConfig" basePath="/base">
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
</http:listener-config>
<apikit-soap:config name="soapkit-config" wsdlLocation="bridge.wsdl" service="Calculator" port="CalculatorSoap12" />
<wsc:config name="Web_Service_Consumer_Config">
    <wsc:connection soapVersion="SOAP12" wsdlLocation="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl" service="Calculator" port="CalculatorSoap12" address="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" />
</wsc:config>
<flow name="api-main">
    <http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/app" allowedMethods="POST, GET" doc:name="Mule Listener" />
    <apikit-soap:router config-ref="soapkit-config">
        <apikit-soap:attributes><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
            output application/java
            ---
            {
                headers: attributes.headers,
                method: attributes.method,
                queryString: attributes.queryString
            }]]]></apikit-soap:attributes>
    </apikit-soap:router>
</flow>
<flow name="Add:\soapkit-config">
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                output application/xml
                ns ns0 http://tempuri.org/
                ---
                {
                    ns0#Add: {
                        ns0#intA: payload.body.ns0#Add.ns0#intA default 0,
                        ns0#intB: payload.body.ns0#Add.ns0#intB default 0
                    }
                }]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
    <wsc:consume config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" operation="Add" doc:name="Outside Consumer" />
 </flow>

If I put a logger after the wsc:consume component, I can see that it sort of works. The outside service is called correctly and returns the right answer. The problem is that the wsc:consume component returns the following in the payload:
{
    body:<AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>579</AddResult></AddResponse>,
    headers: [],
    attachments: []
}

... but what I need is:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <AddResult>579</AddResult>
        </AddResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Another problem is that a ee:transform is required to map the response from the apikit-soap:router to a request format recognized by the wsc:consume component. In some of our SOAP services, the request body contains hundreds of elements. Mapping all of them would be tedious at best. If I could get the apikit-soap:router component to return an XML SOAP Envelope, I think I could replace wsc:consume with an http:request component and no transformation would be needed.
Any suggestions?

The Web Service Consumer was designed so users don't have to deal with the complexity of SOAP. It intentionally doesn't provide access to SOAP details and internals like CXF. If you need to have that level of control you'll need to implement your own web service calls in Java, using some Java SOAP framework of your choice, and use the Java Module to invoke it. Alternatively you can create your own custom connector with the Mule SDK for your specific use case.
Having said that, if you just need to add a basic SOAP Envelope to a message you can just use a DataWeave transformation to do that:
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns soap http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
---
soap#Envelop: {
    soap#Body: read(payload.body, "application/xml")
}

I'm assuming that payload.body is a string containing an XML. If it is an object you remove the read() function.
Output:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap:Envelop xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <AddResult>579</AddResult>
    </AddResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelop>

You can add the other namespaces if the payload uses them.
Also note that Mule 3.9 also has a Web Service Consumer module. You could try to migrate in Mule 3.9 first, however it is probably going to be similar.

@aled Thank you for your answer! I found it extremely helpful, even though I was barking up the wrong tree and asking the wrong questions. The solution I found was to add another ee:transform component after the wsc:consume component. I was also able to simplify my existing ee:transform so that I didn't have to map each individual element. The Add:\soapkit-config flow now looks like this:
<flow name="Add:\soapkit-config">
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Input">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                output application/xml
                ns ns0 http://tempuri.org/
                ---
                payload.body]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
    <wsc:consume config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" operation="Add" doc:name="Outside Consumer" />
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Output">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                output application/xml
                ns ns0 http://tempuri.org/
                ---
                payload.body]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
</flow>

When I put logging components in, I can see that after the Transform Output, the payload looks like this:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <AddResult>579</AddResult>
</AddResponse>

... then control flows back to the SOAP Router which puts the payload into a SOAP Body, so it looks like this:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <AddResult>579</AddResult>
        </AddResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

